# Postgres statement-level trigger ERROR: transition tables cannot be specified for triggers with column lists

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I have a table *my_table* with columns *id* (int), *value* (varchar), and *modified* (timestamp). I want to update the timestamp by the trigger each time I set a new value. I'm changing thousands of rows in one query so I do not want to use the row-level trigger (aka FOR EACH ROW) and modify the whole updated set in one invocation and not the thousands for each row. This is the trigger I'm trying to create:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OF value
ON my_schema.my_table
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS updated OLD TABLE AS prev
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_schema.my_trigger_function()
```

I'm getting an error during the creation:

> [0A000] ERROR: transition tables cannot be specified for triggers with column lists

How can I access the updated data set if I remove the "REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS updated OLD TABLE AS prev" and won't be able to query and join on updated or prev transition tables? If I remove the "OF value" part I'd get the recursive trigger invocation since the trigger fires itself again by changing the same table but a different column. So the best solution I've come up with it's to eliminate the second recursive invocation by the IF condition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON my_schema.my_table
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS updated OLD TABLE AS prev
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_schema.my_trigger_function()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.my_trigger_function()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
               FROM updated
                        INNER JOIN prev ON updated.modified = prev.modified) THEN
        UPDATE my_schema.my_table
        SET modified = NOW()
        WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM updated);
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

If I knew how to access all updated rows with "AFTER UPDATE OF value" without *updated* and *prev* I'd make it better, that's why I'm here.

Comment: A row level (before) trigger with a simple assignment (`new.modified := now();`)  is probably more efficient actually

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you explain deeply why is it more efficient? if I update a million rows by one statement "update my table set value = 'new value' where <some condition>" it fires the statement-level trigger once and would fire 1 million invocations of the row-level trigger

Comment: But your statement level trigger then needs to UPDATE 1 millions rows _again_

Comment: But the error is pretty obvious, isn't it? You can't use a column list (`OF value`) in the trigger definition when using a statement level trigger. Remove that option, and your trigger should work.

Comment: so, as I understand, the row-level trigger works like the filter chain/interceptor before or after the actual modification of each row and a million invocations of it along with the update operation still being one million update operations and it is more efficient than the 2 million simple update operations, yes?

Answer (score -1):

You could avoid recursive invocation of your trigger by adding `WHEN (PG_TRIGGER_DEPTH() = 0)` to the declaration:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON my_schema.my_table
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS updated OLD TABLE AS prev
FOR EACH STATEMENT
WHEN (PG_TRIGGER_DEPTH() = 0)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_schema.my_trigger_function()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use PG_TRIGGER_DEPTH to prevent recursion since it measures all trigger depth, not the depth of the trigger the function is called from. See: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163142/is-pg-trigger-depth-bad-to-use-for-preventing-trigger-cascading-recursion